# SQLite DB Appears Sorted, but I Pull Rows not in the Order of Sort

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I was told when you use .scheme and it says this, it means it is sorted by that index.
[image]

When I pull the rows using:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM DX WHERE studyid='+id)
```

I get results not sorted by that ID. I know I can use ORDER BY, but I want it to work faster, I want the sort to do this for me.

Comment: The physical ordering of rows is an implementation detail. You have to use `order by` if you want to get rows in a specific order. Do you have a performance problem?

Comment: _I was told when you use .scheme and it says this, it means it is sorted by that index_ You were told wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about working faster. If you use ORDER BY, it *will* use that index.

Comment: Oh I get it, just use order by -- thanks guys!!

Answer (score 2):

Without specifying ORDER BY SQLite will very likely utilise the fastest method to return the results and that would be a scan of the **[rowid](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html)** index (that all tables have unless the table has been defined using WITHOUT ROWID). However the order will be according to that index (likely insertion order).

The **rowid** is typically the fastest way that SQLite can get the results. However if you introduce ORDER BY then it will then use the index that best suits and if an index covers the ORDER BY it will be that index.

In short if you want the data to be ORDERED then you must use ORDER BY.

Consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DX;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DX (studyid);
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM DX WHERE studyid = "x";
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM DX WHERE studyid = "x" ORDER BY studyid;
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS DX_IX1 ON DX(studyid);
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM DX WHERE studyid = "x" ORDER BY studyid;
```

The first result (no ORDER BY) shows that table is scanned (i.e. using the rowid (inbuilt B-tree)) :-

[image]

The second result (ORDER BY but no index covering studyid) also scans the table via the inbuilt B-tree :-

[image]

The third result, when the index on the studyid column exists, does use the studyid index as per :-

[image]

If you then consider an example with a reasonable amount of data (100000 rows) using :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DX;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DX2;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DX (studyid);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DX2 (studyid);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS DX_IX1 ON DX2(studyid);
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (SELECT abs(random() % 1000) UNION ALL SELECT abs(random() % 1000) FROM cte LIMIT 100000)
INSERT INTO DX SELECT * FROM cte;
INSERT INTO DX2 SELECT * FROM DX;


SELECT * FROM DX2 WHERE studyid > 1000;
SELECT * FROM DX WHERE studyid > 1000;

SELECT * FROM DX WHERE studyid > 10 AND studyid < 100;
SELECT * FROM DX WHERE studyid > 10 AND studyid < 100 ORDER BY studyid;
SELECT * FROM DX2 WHERE studyid > 10 AND studyid < 100 ORDER BY studyid;

SELECT * FROM DX2 WHERE studyid > 10 AND studyid < 100 ORDER BY studyid;
SELECT * FROM DX WHERE studyid > 10 AND studyid < 100;
SELECT * FROM DX WHERE studyid > 10 AND studyid < 100 ORDER BY studyid;
```

and look at the results (time taken) of the last 6 queries they are :-

```
SELECT * FROM DX WHERE studyid > 10 AND studyid < 100
> OK
> Time: 0.007s


SELECT * FROM DX WHERE studyid > 10 AND studyid < 100 ORDER BY studyid
> OK
> Time: 0.008s


SELECT * FROM DX2 WHERE studyid > 10 AND studyid < 100 ORDER BY studyid
> OK
> Time: 0.003s


SELECT * FROM DX2 WHERE studyid > 10 AND studyid < 100 ORDER BY studyid
> OK
> Time: 0.003s


SELECT * FROM DX WHERE studyid > 10 AND studyid < 100
> OK
> Time: 0.007s


SELECT * FROM DX WHERE studyid > 10 AND studyid < 100 ORDER BY studyid
> OK
> Time: 0.009s
```

Without the index (table DX as opposed to DX2) the times are noticeably longer, and with the ORDER BY clause a little longer than without for the DX table.

However it should also be appreciated that INSERTS, DELETES and some UPDATES will have an overhead of maintaining the index(es).

e.g. here's the timings from the INSERTS :-

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (SELECT abs(random() % 1000) UNION ALL SELECT abs(random() % 1000) FROM cte LIMIT 100000)
INSERT INTO DX SELECT * FROM cte
> Affected rows: 100000
> Time: 0.228s


INSERT INTO DX2 SELECT * FROM DX
> Affected rows: 100000
> Time: 0.362s
```